# Remove item from Laravel Blade Foreach and Update the remaining item value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Hello I am facing an issue of updating the records, what I want to achieve is when user click the close button on the left of the list, the item will be removed. User can input the date and upload the file for each items. When user click on the Request Changes button around the bottom left corner, the remaining item will be updated with the date and file.

I have been wondering if there is any way to do this? What I have tried is when user click the button, the button will return the corresponding item id back to the livewire component and add to a skipRecordList, then make a query only select the rows that id is not in the skipRecordList but somehow doesnt work out for me

I am still new to laravel and livewire, hope could get some hints from you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can look at [this](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-livewire-add-or-remove-dynamically-input-fields-exampleexample.html) example its looks like your question